# Bash / Shell script - How to manupulate a value inside a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I'm currently writing script in Bash and i need to increment some value inside a txt file: 
The file contains this text inside:

```
Major Release Number = 4
Minor Release Number = 1
Service Pack Release Number = 2
Build Number = 21
```

I need to increment the Build Number, i'm wondering how can i do that let's the file name is buildnumber.txt and i have it's directory.

This is part of my script

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# This script is for Incrementing build numbers

path=/home/RND/abrodov
file=tst.txt
newexpr=awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}1' /home/RND/abrodov/tst.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like this,

```
$ awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}1' file
Major Release Number = 4
Minor Release Number = 1
Service Pack Release Number = 2
Build Number = 22
```

Comment: Where do i need to specify the file name ?

Comment: The thing is that the file stays with the same number it's just printing it but not really changin it

Comment: to save the changes made `awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}1' /path/to/inputfile > /path/to/outfile`

Comment: what does the number 1 at the end of the statement statnds for?

Comment: `1` after the last `}` tells the awk to print the lines after the changes made.

Comment: So basically i don't need it , because I'm not going to print it

Comment: no you need to add `1`. did you try this `awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}1' /path/to/inputfile > /path/to/outfile`?

Comment: Yes it's working, so the 1 means print it to the out file it's like cat

Comment: `awk '!/^Build Number / || $4=$4+1' file` works without the "confusing" `1`. =)

Comment: 1 means print it to the standardoutput. `>` redirects all the lines shown in the standard output to the output file.

Comment: or simply try this `awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}{print}' file` last `1` was replaced by `{print}`

Comment: so this is what i wrote in the bash script:
#!/bin/bash -x

# This script is for Incrementing build numbers

path=/home/RND/abrodov
file=tst.txt
newexpr=awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}1' /home/RND/abrodov/tst.txt
and once i run it i get an error:
$ bash ./demoScript.sh
./demoScript.sh: line 7: /^Build Number/{$4=$4+1;}1: No such file or directory
I've edited my question

Comment: There is any way to print just the number that i changed?

Comment: try `awk '/^Build Number/{$4=$4+1; print $4}' file`